# How do I customize the FAST People Search results?

Tags: fast-search, user-profile

I would like to add the user's pager number (which we display the extension) to display in the FAST people search results.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

I modified the FetchProperties on the People Search Code Results web part to include my custom field and now I get this error:

> Property doesn't exist or is used in a
>   manner inconsistent with schema
>   settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of the following link:

http://www.sharepointsteve.com/2010/10/making-custom-user-profile-properties-searchable-in-sharepoint-2010/

Lot more to this than I expected ... but it does work.